# Can't import the nsIDOMGeoGeolocation XPCOM Interface

Tags: firefox, firefox-addon, firefox-addon-sdk

Using the addon-sdk of firefox I'm following a tutorial about creating reusable modules, the example uses the [geolocation API built into Firefox](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/WebAPI/Using_geolocation), so the code is simple:

```
function getCurrentPosition(callback){
    var xpcomGeolocation = Cc["@mozilla.org/geolocation;1"].getService(Ci.nsIDOMGeoGeolocation);
 xpcomGeolocation.getCurrentPosition(callback);
}

var widget = require("sdk/widget").Widget({ 
    id: "whereami",
    label: "Where Am I?",
    contentURL: "http://www.mozilla.org/favicon.ico",
    onClick: function(){
        console.log("clicked!");        
        getCurrentPosition(function(position){
            console.log("latitude: " + position.coords.latitude);
            console.log("longitude: " + position.coords.longitude);
        });
    }
});
```

When running firefox with the plugin on, clicking the widget give this error:

`Message: [Exception... "Component returned failure code: 0x80570018 (NS_ERROR_XPC_BAD_IID) [nsIJSCID.getService]"  nsresult: "0x80570018 (NS_ERROR_XPC_BAD_IID)"  location: "JS frame :: resource://gre/modules/XPIProvider.jsm -> jar:file:///tmp/tmpTFowYc.mozrunner/extensions/jid1-LIBIfbK6zvWAiQ@jetpack.xpi!/bootstrap.js -> resource://gre/modules/commonjs/toolkit/loader.js -> resource://jid1-libifbk6zvwaiq-at-jetpack/whereami/lib/main.js :: getCurrentPosition :: line 7"  data: no]`

Answer (score 1):

[According to docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/XPCOM_Interface_Reference/NsIDOMGeoGeolocation#Method_Overview), it's possible to get an error when importing `nsIDGeoGeolocation` so you must use `Cc["@mozilla.org/geolocation;1"].getService(Ci.nsISupports);` instead. Also, you must ask for permission to access geolocation, please see section **Prompting for permission** in 
[Using geolocation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/WebAPI/Using_geolocation)
 reference.

By the way, as an advice, I think it will be simpler to use `navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(successCallback, errorCallback)` since it handles prompting for permission for you, but I don't know what are you trying to do beyond this. Just to explain it a little, you could have an addon page `data/index.html` where you tell the user you are going to prompt him for his geolocation. Besides this, you must have a PageMod that runs a `data/script.js` for that addon page page, which has access to `navigator.geolocation`. That content script may communicate with your `lib/main.js` file so it has access to the user geo location. Somethings like this:

`data/index.html`:

```
<html>
  <body>
    <h1>Hello user!</h1>
  </body>
</html>
```

`data/script.js`:

```
var successCallback = function(position) {
    /* this way this script will talk to the pagemod in lib/main.js the user's position */
    self.port.emit("gotGeolocation", position.coords.latitude, position.coords.longitude);
};
navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(successCallback, errorCallback);
```

`lib/main.js`:

```
var data = require("sdk/self").data;
var pageMod = require("sdk/page-mod");
var tabs = require("sdk/tabs");

pageMod.PageMod({
  /* attach the contentScriptFile to this html page */
  include: data.url("index.html"),
  contentScriptFile: data.url("script.js"),
  onAttach: function(worker) {
    /* listen to the script.js worker "gotGeolocation" message */
    worker.port.on("gotGeolocation", function(latitude, longitude) {
      console.log("latitude:", latitude);
      console.log("longitude:", longitude);
    });
  }
});

/* this will open the index.jtml page and promt the user to access his geo position */
tabs.open(data.url("index.html"));
```

All this code it's only to better describe the idea, it hasn't been tested and in fact there are some indefinded objects. But I hope to give you an idea of how you can acces navigator.geolocation and pass its coords to the main.js script.

Comment: the sdk doesn't provide an API to access geolocation with navigator.geolocation. I tried with nsISupports and have another error. All I'm trying to do is complete the tutorial.

Comment: I have edited my previous answer to explain how you can access navigator object. Hope it helps.

Comment: Thanks I'm pretty sure injecting a script in content pages will work this out with `navigator` but I want to access the chrome service, and don't know why I can't, and If I'm doing it wrong.

Comment: ok, please edit your question to show us what error are you getting when you use `nsISupports` instead of `nsIDGeoGeolocation`.

Answer (score 0):

I think that you just forgot this at the top:

```
var { Cc, Ci } = require('chrome');
```

Also there a third party module for geolocation https://github.com/ZER0/geolocation